# Brownian motion question for $\mathbb{E}\left[W_s W_t^2 \right]$ and $\mathbb{E}\left[W_s^2 W_t^2 \right]$

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, expected-value

> Let $\{W_t:t \ge 0\}$ be a Brownian motion. Find for all $0 \le s < t$:
>
> - $\mathbb{E}\left[W_s W_t \right]$
> - $\mathbb{E}\left[W_s W_t^2 \right]$
> - $\mathbb{E}\left[W_s^2 W_t^2 \right]$
> - $\mathbb{E}\left[\left. e^{2W_t} \right| \mathcal{F}_s\right]$
>
> **Hint:** Recall that the kurtosis for $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ is $\mathbb{E}\left[Z^4\right] = 3$.

I am confused. I think based on the theory, $\mathbb{E}\left[W_s W_t \right]$ should be $s$, and then I do not understand what I should do for $\mathbb{E}\left[W_s W_t^2 \right]$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Recall that you want to use independent increments, so
$$
\mathbb{E}[W_s W_t]
 = \mathbb{E}[W_s (W_s + W_{s,t})]
 = \mathbb{E}[W_s^2] + \mathbb{E}[W_s W_{s,t}]
 = s+\mathbb{E}[W_s] \mathbb{E}[ W_{s,t}]
 = s,
$$
where $W_{s,t}$ is the process starting at $s$ and evolving until $t$.

Can you use a similar argument to solve others?